# Do not sort the history column in BindingSource C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

not sort the history column

Changes are not applied and are displayed in unsorted dataGridView1

```
            BindingSource bi = new BindingSource();
            int cp = int.Parse(comnlotsabt.Text);

            var m = db.DLaboratory.Where(x => x.NuLot == cp).ToList();

            bi.DataSource = m;

            bi.Sort = "Cdate DESC";

            dataGridView1.DataSource = bi;
```

Comment: What is the type of `m`? Please post the class structure of `m` too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .OrderByDescending(x => x.Cdate) on the linq query

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingSource()
{
     Datasource = db.DLaboratory
                  .Where(x => x.NuLot == int.Parse(comnlotsabt.Text))
                  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Cdate)
                  .ToList()
};
```